# View [.mail.index] not found

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy intentando enviar mails con Laravel pero tuve que mover un par de carpetas para poder hacer la página traducible, lo que me generó un problema con los directorios que no estoy pudiendo arreglar.
Ya probé con

`return $this->view('../emails.mails');`

pero tampoco funcionó.

El archivo donde se encuentra el formulario que envia el Mail está en la carpeta "Español" e "Inglés".

**Web.php**

```
Route::get('/mail', 'merluzaController@mail');
```

**merluzaController.php**

```
   public function mail(request $request){
        Mail::to('ltomicb@gmail.com')->send(new mdpMail($request));
        Session::flash('mensaje_enviado','Mensaje enviado correctamente.');
        return redirect('/contacto');
    }
```

**mdpMail.php**

```
use Queueable, SerializesModels;

public $datos;

public function __construct($request)
{
    $this->datos = $request;
}

public function build()
{
    return $this->view('emails.mails');
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Si modificaste la ruta por defecto de laravel para las vistas, debes dirigirte al archivo `config/view.php` y poner tu nueva ruta.

```
'paths' => [
        resource_path('views'), // Esta ruta indica 'resources/views' que es por defecto
    ],
```

No es necesario hacer `$this->view()`, simplemente debes hacer `return view('admin.profile');`

Comment: No cambié la ruta por defecto para las vistas, sigue siendo Views.

Comment: La ruta por defecto es `resources/views`, dentro de `resources`.

Comment: Podrías mostrar la ruta completa de tu vista `emails.mails`?

Comment: MerluzaDePincho\resources\views\emails\mails.blade.php